# Custom Select Options Value Show Zero

Tags: magento-1.9.1.1

I am creating a custom module. I have a form which have some fields.
Here are fields.
[image]

All Fields are working Fine.. But `08`,`09` Field show `0` Value in Admin Form.

[image]

Any Idea to solve this one.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to define value like a string:

```
array(
    'value' => '09',
    'label' => Mage::helper('timer')->__('09')
)
```

Comment: Yes its working..